# XCode Stack Views not showing properly

Tags: ios, xcode, stack, uistackview, stackview

I'm currently trying to achieve the following look:

[image: without stack views]

I have 4 stack views which are in nested into one final stack view, and I get the following result:

[image: embedded in stack views]

Can someone help me with some pointers how to achieve the look of the first image? I'm fairly new to stack views, I've looked up a fair of tutorials on stack views but haven't seen any explaining how to get the spacing above and below the sliders.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer stackView (depicted with the white border) needs spacing. Looks like it's spacing is set to 0

Then for the sliders and their respective values - you can go about laying them out in 1 of 2 ways:

- Either keep your current layout and just embed those stackViews
  (purple and light blue) in a vertical stackView with some spacing, or
- Embed each slider with it's value in a vertical stackView and then embed
  those 3 stackViews in a horizontal stackView